# Are the following quotient spaces finite dimensional?

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

If we take $\mathbb{F}[x]$ to be the set of all polynomials over the field $\mathbb{F}$, $E$ to be the subset of all such even polynomials, $N$ to be the set of these polynomials that have degree less than or equal to $n$ and $x^nP$ to be the set of these polynomials that are multiples of $x^n$, then are the quotient spaces $\mathbb{F}[x]/N$, $\mathbb{F}[x]/E$ and $\mathbb{F}[x]/x^nP$ finite dimensional?

I do see how to get a basis for a quotient space from one for the space and one for its subspace but I can't decide whether or not they're finite dimensional, especially for these examples! Could you help me by treating one of these cases in details to I can see where I misunderstand?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean "even polynomials"??

Comment: Those spanned by ${1_\mathbb{F}, x^2, x^4, ...}$

Comment: Ok, so the space of all polynomials all of which monomials are of even degree.

Comment: Wait: if you add $\;1_{\Bbb F}\;$ then the set is **not** what I wrote above. Shouldn't you take it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$\dim_{\Bbb F}\Bbb F[x]=\infty\;,\;\;\dim_{\Bbb F}N=n+1\implies \dim_{\Bbb F}\Bbb F[x]/N=\infty$$

For $\;\Bbb F[x]/E\;$ , we have that

$$x+E\;,\;\;(x+x^3)+E\;,\ldots,(x+x^{2n-1})+E\;,\ldots$$

are all linearly independent in the quotient space, since

$$\sum_{k=0}^na_k\left((x+x^{2k-1})+E\right)=\overline 0 (=E)\;,\;\;a_k\in\Bbb F\iff$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(a_kx+a_kx^{2k-1})=\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_k\right)x+\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^{2k-1}\right)\in E\iff$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^na_k=0\;,\;and\;\;a_k=0\;\;\forall\,k$$

Now you try some attack on the third case.

Comment: $P$ is $E$ here, right? I'm looking at the third one right now!

Comment: Sorry about the typo. Editing now

Comment: Also, are you then concluding the second is infinite dimensional? Shouldn't all subsets of the potential basis be shown to be independent?

Comment: You have to show that *any finite* subset of the infinite set in lin. independent. Since any such subset can be taken from $\;k=0\;$ and up to $\;k=n\;$ , for some  natural $\;n\;$ , the above covers all cases.

Comment: Oh, right, thank you! I'd say the last one is finite dimensional, it has basis $\{ s + x^nP:s\in\{1,x,x^2,...,x^{n-1}\} \}$

Comment: @Noome, I completely agree with you... *as long as you can prove it*, of course. Can you?

Comment: The same way you did with the second quotient set, except it's even simpler! Right?

Comment: Yes, right... *except* that in this case you *also* need to prove the set you're giving is a generator set. After all, if that set is lin. ind. then it can be part of an **infinite** basis...

Comment: Yes, I've got that one too (using that every linear combination of $x^k$'s with $k\geq n$ is in $x^nP$)